# How to run a Python project with a Maven/MVC folder structure

Tags: python, command-line, pycharm

I used PyCharm to develop a project that I now need to run on the command line, but I can't figure out how to do this.

If I want to use a classic Maven-MVC folder structure as outlined below, how do I get this to work with Python?  Do I need to have an `__init__.py` file somewhere?  If so where?

```
   project1
   └───src
       └───main
           ├───python
           │   ├───app
           │   │       Main.py
           │   │
           │   ├───control
           │   │       ThingControl.py
           │   │
           │   └───model
           │           ThingModel.py
           │
           └───resource
                   Image01.png
```

While developing with PyCharm, I could import my Python files like this:

```
from src.main.python.app.model.ThingModel import ThingModel
```

But when I try to run from the command line with this command:

```
py C:\path\to\project\src\main\python\app\Main.py
```

Main.py begins to execute, but the imports don't work.  `src.main.python.app.model` can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try setting your `PYTHONPATH` to (I don't do windows, so I don't know how to start a windows path) `.../path/to/project/source/main/python`
2. Your import would then be something like `from app.model.ThingModel import ThingModel`
3. You will also need a `__init__.py` file in each of your python directories.
4. In `PyCharm`, set the `.../path/to/project/source/main/python` directory as your `source root`